# php select count(*) from a session email from navbar..Why does not work?

Tags: php, session, select, count, echo

I want to count how many emails can i find in my database(unique record, i expect to return 1)
This is how my php code looks like..ads is my table from database(check the picture)

```
    <?php
    session_start();
                 $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","job_portal");
                 $query="SELECT COUNT(email) as total FROM ads WHERE email='{$_SESSION['email']}'";
                $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                $values=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                $num_rows=$values['total'];

    ?>

    <h3><?php echo $num_rows ?></h3>
```

When I use echo to print out the result, all i get it's "0".

> I also tried to write php sintax like this
>   "myemailfromthedatabase@yahoo.com" to check if the sintax it's correctly written

```
 $query="SELECT COUNT(email) as total FROM ads WHERE email='myemailfromdatabase@yahoo.com'";
```

**aaand again all i get is ZERO("0") but the email exist in the database**

*A funny thing is that when  i'm trying to log in with a different email so $_SESSION['email'], will be different , the PHP sintax WORKS for this!
It works just for specific emails-don't understand why :(*
Can you guys help me, please?

[This is the "ads" database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCJgA.png)

P.S. I am a beginner! :)

Comment: did you check what is the output of `print_r($values);` ? If you did, could you add this output, or at least its structure to your question? This is basic troubleshooting.

Comment: 1) You didn't add the '$' to 'conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","job_portal");'

Comment: 2) use PHP function bindParam to use php variable like this '$query->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['email'])' and replace it with a '?'

Comment: 3) use $query->prepare("YOUR QUERY"); to prevent your query from SQL injections